# Trying to copy an array, sort the copy before I sort the original, and then compare the copy and original while the original is being sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, copy, selection-sort

I have a selection-sort algorithm that sorts 47 different vertical red bars into an order lowest to highest. During the sorting, I want the bars that are placed in the correct position to turn blue. The way I want to do this is to copy my barHeight array, sort the copy, and then see if the original array bars match up with the already sorted copy bars while the original is in the process of being sorted. I have copied and sorted my barHeight array in my arrayCopy method. In drawBar, I have an if statement that says that if a bar in the original barHeight method matches the copy, then it will be drawn as blue, so I thought I had everything, but the program just isn't working. There aren't any error messages, but none of the bars turn blue and I've no clue why. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;


public class Lab15st extends Applet
{

    private int numBars;        // number of bars to be sorted
    private int barHeight[];    // array of bar heights
    private int sortDelay;      // delay between comparison iteration
    private int secondBarHeight[]; //copy of barHeight array

    public void init()
    {
        numBars = 47;
        sortDelay = 50;  // Change to 50 is using the "Selection Sort".
        barHeight = new int[numBars];
        secondBarHeight = new int[numBars];
        arrayCopy();
        getBarValues();
    }

    public void getBarValues()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(3333);
        for (int k = 0; k < numBars; k++)
            barHeight[k] = rand.nextInt(591) + 10;  // range of 10..600
    }

   public void arrayCopy()
   {
        int[] secondBarHeight = barHeight.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
        int min = secondBarHeight[i];
        int minId = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < secondBarHeight.length; j++) {
           if (secondBarHeight[j] < min) {
               min = secondBarHeight[j];
               minId = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = secondBarHeight[i];
        secondBarHeight[i] = min;
        secondBarHeight[minId] = temp;
      }
   }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        showFrame(g);
        displayBars(g);
        sortBars(g);
    }

    public void showFrame(Graphics g)
    {
        Expo.setBackground(g,Expo.black);
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,20,20,980,630);
    }

    public void drawBar(Graphics g, int k)
    {  
      int y2 = 630;
        int x1 = 35 + k * 20;
        int y1 = y2 - barHeight[k];
        int x2 = x1 + 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++){
        if(barHeight[i] == secondBarHeight[i])
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.blue);
        else
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);
        }
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }

    public void eraseBar(Graphics g, int k) 
    {
        int y2 = 630;
        int x1 = 35 + k * 20;
        int y1 = y2 - barHeight[k];
        int x2 = x1 + 10;
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }

    public void displayBars(Graphics g)
    {  
        for (int k = 0; k < numBars; k++)
            drawBar(g,k);
    }

    public void swap(Graphics g, int m, int n)  
    {                                           
     Expo.delay(sortDelay);
     
     eraseBar(g,m);
     eraseBar(g,n);
     
     int temp = barHeight[m];
     barHeight[m] = barHeight[n];
     barHeight[n] = temp;
     
     drawBar(g,m);
     drawBar(g,n);
   }

    public void sortBars(Graphics g)            
    {                                           
     for (int p = 0; p < numBars; p++)
      {
       int smallest = findSmallestItemIndex(p);
       if (barHeight[p] != barHeight[smallest])
         swap(g,p,smallest);
      }
   }

   public int getItem(int index) { 
     return barHeight[index]; 
    }

   public int findSmallestItemIndex(int start)
   {
     int smallest = start;
     for (int k = start+1; k < numBars; k++)
     if (barHeight[k] < barHeight[smallest])
       smallest = k;
     return smallest;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sea one suspicious line in your code in `arrayCopy()` method:
`int[] secondBarHeight = barHeight.clone();`
You define local variable whereas there is class field with such name.
So you may think that you work with class field whereas you modify local variable and class field remains unmodified.